# If $G<S_n$ is transitive, calculate $1/|G| \cdot \sum_{g \in G} f(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions, fixed-point-theorems

$G<S_n$ is transitive

calculate $1/|G| * \sum_{g \in G} f(g)$

where $G<S_n$ and $f(g) = |\{ 1 \le i \le n | g(i) = i \}|$

I tried to use the orbit stabiliser theorem but didn't get anywhere

any hint or solution will be very appriciated

Comment: See [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma)

Comment: You do need the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem for this. Calculate the double sum $|\{ g \in G, i \in X : g(i) = i \}|$ (where $S_n$ permutes the set $X$) in two different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma), $1/|G| \cdot \sum_{g \in G} f(g)$  is equal to the number of orbits under the action of $G$. Since $G$ is transitive, the sum is $1$.